# Jython script error

Tags: weblogic, jython

I am trying to add the following in the config.xml of weblogic server under `<server>` node

```
<ssl>

  <enabled>true</enabled>

</ssl>
```

I can do this using admin console, but I have to use the jython script so that it can be done while installing the application.

I followed the steps explained in here -

http://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/2010/04/record_and_play_your_weblogic.html

It generates the following script -

```
cd('/Servers/ocsServer')
cmo.setListenPortEnabled(true)

cmo.setJavaCompiler('javac')

cmo.setClientCertProxyEnabled(false)

cd('/Servers/ocsServer/SSL/ocsServer')

cmo.setEnabled(true)

activate()

startEdit()
```

But I am getting this exception -

```
com.bea.plateng.domain.script.
jython.WLSTException: com.bea.plateng.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: com.bea.plateng.domain.script.ScriptException: No nested element SSL is found
```

Any idea?

Comment: does lower-case `ssl` make any diff?

Comment: when I use lower-case ssl I get this


com.bea.plateng.domain.script.j
ython.WLSTException: com.bea.plateng.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: java.la
ng.UnsupportedOperationException: Could not create generic operation:ssl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually necessary to create a new SSL MBean as a child of the Server MBean, the same way you would with log configuration:

```
cd('/Servers/ocsServer')
ssl = create('ocsServer','SSL')
ssl.setEnabled(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not specify which version of WebLogic Server you are using but I'm ssuming 10.x. Can you check if the MBean hierarchy is ok by firing up wlst from a command prompt and checking the objects manually:

```
connect('weblogic','weblogic-passsword','t3://your-hostname:your-port')
edit()
cd('/Servers/ocsServer')
ls()
```

Do you see an "SSL" MBean hierarchy node in the listing?